# How to add index for hstore on postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I only need to add an index to a key in hstore column.

My query like this :

`select ... from table where tags->'place'='xxx'`

And I try it

```
create index "inx_tags_place" on nodes _col((tags->'place'));
```

but I get

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "_col"
LINE 1: create index "inx_tags_place" on nodes _col((tags->'place'))...
                                               ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 40
```

Does PostgreSQL allow add index for one key in hstore?

Comment: You didn't specify the index type. `_col` doesn't mean anything. It should be `on nodes using gist(....)` where gist could be, gist, gin, btree, hash, depending on the index type you require for your querying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an incorrect syntax to create your indexes.

If you want to index only a single element from the "tags" hstore then use btree like so

`create index "nodes_tags_place_idx" on nodes using btree((tags->'place'))`

To index the whole "tags" column you can use gin, meaning you could index a search on any key, however this index will be much larger for obvious reasons.

`create index "nodes_tags_idx" on nodes using gin(tags)`

Comment: I get SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "->"

Comment: @Luffydude needs extra brackets around the hstore query segment.